# Calling a Activity method from BroadcastReceiver in Android when BroadcastReceiver app is not started

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a Broadcastreceiver in my ReceiverApp, which I call from my SenderApp and this works fine.
I would like to call a method of the Activity in my ReceiverApp.

How can I do that with the following prerequisites ? :

- The ReceiverApp was not started and dynamically registering the receiver is not possible.
- I can't call the Receivers Mainactivity from my Sender, because I would like to prevent showing any ActivityScreen of the Receiver. The Sender should just call an ReceiverActivity method and proceed further, so the Senderscreen should be always on top.
- I cant do the ReceiverActivity Method "static", because then I loose the context of the Activity. I need for example to fetch the Packagename of the Receiver with : `this.getPackageName()`

  ```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // Extract data included in the Intent
          CharSequence intentData = intent.getCharSequenceExtra("message");  
          Toast.makeText(context, "Say : "+intentData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          MainActivity.myMethod(); <<<<<--------

      }
  ```

  }

Any hint or help ?

Comment: if you want to call a method inside an `Activity` but without that `Activity` being in the foreground, then why have you put that method inside the `Activity` in the first place ??

Comment: Good question :-) Because I need the context of the Activity. For example to get the packagename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, what you want is impossible. If the activity does not exist, you cannot call methods on it.

Move your code to some common location that is accessible from both the receiver and the activity, such as a static method.

> I cant do the ReceiverActivity Method "static", because then I loose the context of the Activity.

Pass a `Context` as a parameter to the method.

> I need for example to fetch the Packagename of the Receiver with : this.getPackageName()

Call `getPackageName()` on the `Context` that is passed into `onReceive()`.

Comment: "Call getPackageName() on the Context that is passed into onReceive()". Thats the Context of the sender. But I need the context of the receiver. Same for Passing the Parameter . I can only pass the Sender Context, but I need the receiver context. I see, that I'll have to do with calling the Activity directly insteed of using broadcasting.

Comment: @user1344545: "But I need the context of the receiver" -- the package name is the same in either case, as that is for your app. Hence, you do not need the "receiver" `Context`. "but I need the receiver context" -- why?

Comment: Packagename is only a sample. Off course I would know the packagename myself. This was only a sample. I need the entire stuff for my License verification in my special situation, which can't be explained easely.

Comment: I will accept the answer, because you stated "By definition, what you want is impossible". After further researches I beleave you :-)